# how to drawimage same with red block

Tags: javascript, canvas

A red block on image, size is `50*50`, and image origin size is `320*180`, image element size is `200*113`

now I want to get the red block and draw on canvas, but I have no idea how to calculate, please let me know `why` and `how`!!

my sample code here

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("scream");
  const naturalWidth = img.naturalWidth;
  const naturalHeight = img.naturalHeight;
  const ratio = naturalWidth / img.offsetWidth;
  const heightRatio = naturalHeight / img.offsetHeight;
  const canvasRatio = naturalWidth / c.width;
  const canvasYRatio = naturalHeight / c.height;
  console.log(ratio, heightRatio, canvasRatio);
  const r = 1/(naturalWidth/naturalHeight);
  console.log(r);
  const width = 50;
  const height = 50;
  const top = 50 * heightRatio;
  const left = 90 * ratio;
  
  ctx.drawImage(img, -left, -top);
};
```

```css
body{
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img id="scream" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/uwMQRAC1JE8/mqdefault.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="200">
<div style="
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
"></div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="50" height="50" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;display:block" />
```

Comment: I am not a web developer, but the size of the red frame seems to be 50*60.

Comment: shit, my mistake....typo

Comment: Just a debugging tip. Try to replace variables with hardcoded values, and check whether you are getting right result or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the long version of [*`ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, swidth, sheight, dx, dy, dwidth, dheight)`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) in order to be able to crop and resize the original image.

The short 2 arguments version is simply drawing the original image at the orignal size, with some offset on the destination, but you need to apply the resizing on your output too.

So using the long version you can do

```
 ctx.drawImage(img,
 // source
   x * ratioW,
   y * ratioH,
   width * ratioW,
   height * ratioH,
 // destination
   0,
   0,
   width,
   height
 );
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  var img = document.getElementById("scream");
  const naturalWidth = img.naturalWidth;
  const naturalHeight = img.naturalHeight;
  const ratio = naturalWidth / img.offsetWidth;
  const heightRatio = naturalHeight / img.offsetHeight;
  const canvasRatio = naturalWidth / c.width;
  const canvasYRatio = naturalHeight / c.height;
  const r = 1/(naturalWidth/naturalHeight);
  console.log(r);
  const width = 50;
  const height = 50;
  const top = 50 * heightRatio;
  const left = 90 * ratio;
  
  ctx.drawImage(
    img,
    left, top, width * ratio, height * heightRatio,
    0, 0, width, height
  );
};
```

```css
body{
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img id="scream" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/uwMQRAC1JE8/mqdefault.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="200">
<div style="
    position: absolute;
    left: 90px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
"></div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="50" height="50" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;display:block" />
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I used the wrong function, but why the canvas quantity is so bad, how can I fix it?